# @Valid annotation not stopping blank fields

Tags: java, spring, jsp, annotations

I am trying to create a Form in JSP and use `@Valid` annotation for the validations. When I press the submit button without entering anything in the form, empty values are inserted in my database. The print statement in the Controller prints empty values for all fields, which suggests that the `@Valid` annotation is not working. What am I doing wrong?? Here are my files:

User Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "User_Id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "Username")
    @NotBlank(message = "Username cannot be empty!")
    @NotNull(message = "Username cannot be empty!")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+", message = "Only alphanumeric characters allowed !")
    private String userName;
    
    @Column(name = "Password")
    @NotBlank(message = "Password cannot be empty!")
    @NotNull(message = "Password cannot be empty!")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9 _!@#&.]+", message = "Password pattern mismatch !")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name = "Name")
    @NotBlank(message = "Name cannot be empty!")
    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be empty!")
    private String name;
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView registerPage(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User user = new User();
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        System.out.println(user.getName() + "-" + user.getUserName() + "-" + user.getPassword());
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        } else {
            userService.saveUser(user);
            modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "User has been registered successfully");
            modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
            modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

JSP:

```
<form:form action="register" method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
    
        <p>Name</p>
        <form:input path="name"/>
        <form:errors path="name"/>

        <p>*Username</p>
        <form:input path="userName"/>
        <form:errors path="userName"/>

        <p>*Password</p>
        <form:input path="password"/>
        <form:errors path="password"/>

        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />

    </form:form>
```

I even tried adding the following dependency, but still it didn't work:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try adding ex. '@NotBlank' there as well as Valid. For now it checking for validation rules but there are none.

Comment: Make sure you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` on the classpath and that you haven't accidently added `hibernate-validator` yourself (as you probably would have added version 7 which isn't supported).

Comment: @M.Deinum  I have it on classpath. Also, none of the import statements are of hibernate-validator.

Comment: the imports shouldn't but javax.validation is an API you need an implementation which is `hibernate-validator`. Now as I stated only up to version 6 is supported as `hibernate-validator` version 7 is an implementation of jakarta validation and not jvavax.validation.